# Cannot use make_constructor in boost::python when declaring external constructor

Tags: boost-python

I'm trying to defined an external constructor when porting a class to python, by using make_constructor absolutely fails.  When I try:

```
#include <boost/python/numpy.hpp>
using boost::python;

class foo
{
    int i;
public:
    foo(int i) : i(i){}
};

foo foo_create(int i){return foo(i);}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(bar)
{
    class_<foo>("foo")
        .def("__init__", make_constructor(&foo_create));
}
```

I get the following error

```
error: no type named ‘element_type’ in ‘class foo’
```

I tried using noinit and init() with the same result.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Awe found the problem, part of it being the really sparse documentation on make_construction.  I needed to return a ptr to a new instance like so (in this case I made them shared pointers):

```
#include <boost/python/numpy.hpp>
#include <memory>
using boost::python;

class foo
{
    int i;
public:
    foo(int i) : i(i){}
};

std::shared_ptr<foo> foo_create(int i){return std::shared_ptr<foo>(foo(i));}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(bar)
{
    class_<foo, std::shared_ptr<foo>>("foo")
        .def("__init__", make_constructor(&foo_create));
}
```

The documentation on make_constructor is really sparse, but there is some discussion here:  https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/HowTo under point "9".